# Summarizing css classes don't work

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using different Font Awesome icons and I tried to summarize this lines:

css

```
ul.long_arrow_right,ul.minus,ul.long_arrow_circle_right   {list-style: none;}
ul.long_arrow_right         > li:before {content:"\f178"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;}
ul.minus                    > li:before {content:"\f068"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;}
ul.long_arrow_circle_right  > li:before {content:"\f0a9"; font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;}
```

For using Font Awesome you need to include it to the html head.

html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

css-code, which doesn't work correct

```
ul.long_arrow_right         > li:before {content:"\f178";}
ul.minus                    > li:before {content:"\f068";}
ul.long_arrow_circle_right  > li:before {content:"\f0a9";}
ul.long_arrow_right,ul.minus,ul.long_arrow_circle_right   {list-style: none;}
ul.long_arrow_right,ul.minus,ul.long_arrow_circle_right > li:before {font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;}
```

Isn't it possible to summarize this css code?

Comment: what do you mean by `summarize`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here

Comment: Like in my question: I want to have the duplicate commands `font-family: FontAwesome;display: block;float: left;width: 1.5em;` only once, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> css-code, which doesn't work correct

Explaining this rule

```
ul.long_arrow_right,ul.minus,ul.long_arrow_circle_right > li:before {}
```

it selects these elements

```
<ul class='long_arrow_right'></ul>
<ul class='minus'></ul>
<ul class='long_arrow_circle_right'><li></li></ul>  //the li is selected
```

So it targets 2 `ul` element and `li's` under the `ul.long_arrow_circle_right`. You need to change the selector.

what you would want is

```
 ul.long_arrow_right > li:before ,ul.minus > li:before ,ul.long_arrow_circle_right > li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 1.5em;
}
```

---

---

**Or** you can set a class to all the `ul` elements which need this rule and then just simply do this.

```
 ul.fontAwesomeRule > li:bfore{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 1.5em;
 }
```

So go ahead and add this class `fontAwesomeRule` to all the `ul` elements which you want to target.